# Can't compile C++ program on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

I used OSX to program in C++, but I am new to C++ compiler on Linux.  I have a program consisting two .cpp files and one .h file that are compiled and run successfully on my Mac, but get compiling errors on Ubuntu.  I did  install gcc and g++ compilers and build-essential, and also apt-get update and update, searched online, but in no vain.  Does my Ubuntu lack of some library packages or some extra configuration needed to fix the problem?

Here is my program's compiling errors on Ubuntu:

```
WordCombine.cpp: In function ‘int BuildTrie(const string&, Trie*&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)’:
WordCombine.cpp:21:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const string&, const openmode&)’
  ifstream ifs(filename, ifstream::in);
                                     ^
WordCombine.cpp:21:37: note: candidates are:
In file included from WordCombine.cpp:10:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:467:7: note: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
       basic_ifstream(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:467:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:453:7: note: std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]
       basic_ifstream() : __istream_type(), _M_filebuf()
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:453:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:427:11: note: std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)
     class basic_ifstream : public basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>
           ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/fstream:427:11: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

Here is my g++ -v info:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
```

Comment: How about showing the lines of *source code* that produce the errors?  That said, "no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’" suggests you're lacking the C++11 constructor that accepts the filename as a `std::string` (under C++03 you needed to provide a `const char*`) - try adding `-std=c++11` to your compiler command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to use the `std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(const string&, const openmode&)` constructor, and according to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream), that was a C++11 addition.

You'll probably need to add `-std=c++11` to your command line, since it isn't the default.

Comment: If you don't want to use C++11 (but I guess that you want to, since your Mac compiler seems to have used C++11 by default) you could just convert the `std::string` to a `const char*`: `ifstream ifs(filename.c_str(), ifstream::in)`.

Comment: Conversely, you can install clang on Linux too, and use the same compiler on both platforms. That will at least reduce the number of quirks you need to remember.